# Birthday Journey with Sql query in Automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql, automationstudio

I have created a Journey with Automation for birthday.

I have a data extension with birthday field, using which I have created an automation to include only the customer's having birthday's on the day automation is running.(Automation is running midnight 12 everyday).

The query is :

```
SELECT NAME, [DOB],Email, RMNumber
FROM Birthday_Test
WHERE DAY([DOB]) = DAY(GETDATE())
    AND MONTH([DOB]) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

The query helps to only include customer's with birthday on today's date to the target data extension.

This target data extension is used as an entry source in Journey builder.

Issue: When I did run once, it worked well then I scheduled it and in midnight emails were sent to the same previous day's birthday's.

next day the automation worked properly and so the journey.

third day there was no birthday of any customer(I have selected to overwrite the data in target data extension), but as there was no birthday,no action was taken and again emails were sent to the same people with previous day's birthdays.

what can be done to this???
Can anyone help.

Comment: Can you check the settings you have in `Contact Evaluation` in the Journey `Schedule`?

Comment: You could try to make **contact evaluation** into the journey - to allow new records only.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a Wait period to the end of your journey and set it to hold people for 11 months and then make sure the setting is to allow re-entry only after exit in Journey Settings this will work. The SQL you have put on there is fine